# Trying to split text into lines, and then tabs. Get only first line

Tags: c, string

I have a char array (buf) that exists out of multiple lines and each line is split up by multiple tabs. I want to separate this. I use the following code for this:

```
char copy[4096];
char* split_request = strtok(buf, "\r\n");
strcpy(copy, split_request);

while(split_request != NULL) {  

    if (strchr(copy, '\t') != NULL) {
        printf("We have a tab"); 
    
        //If I uncomment this line I get an assertion error
        //char* temp = strtok(copy, '\t'); 
    }


    printf(split_request); 
    split_request = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
    if (split_request != NULL) {
        strcpy(copy, split_request);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

If I uncomment that one line of code, only the first line is processed. In addition, it is printed 5 times, and each time one tabbed column disappears. It feels like despite the strcpy, the original string is still affected...

Comment: As a side note, `printf(split_request);` is dangerous because `split_request` may contain `%`. It should be `fputs(split_request, stdout);` or `printf("%s", split_request);`.

Comment: `strtok()` cannot hold multiple sessions at once. [`strtok_r()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) should be useful if your environment supports that.

Comment: If you don't want to use a platform-specfic replacement for the function [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) (which was mentioned in another comment), then you may want to consider using the function [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) or [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experimenting with an alternative approach to your problem. I have used strtok_r for separating lines and each line is processed using strtok for tabs. The code is given below.

```
void lineParser(char *singleLine){
    const char tab[] = "\t";
    char *token = NULL;
    if(strchr(singleLine, '\t') != NULL){
        token = strtok(singleLine, tab);
        while(token != NULL){
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, tab);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char buf[] = "Stack\tOverFlow\r\nStack\tExchange\r\n";
    char *rest = buf;;
    char* token = NULL;
    const char tab[] = "\t";
    const char newline[] = "\r\n";

    while ((token = strtok_r(rest, " ", &rest))) {         
        lineParser(token);
        token = strtok_r(rest, newline, &rest);         
    }

}
```